# Display PostgreSQL DB contents back to HTML with Thymeleaf and JSP

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am creating a Spring Boot application in which I have to consume this [API](https://bitpay.com/api/rates), add it's JSON contents to a PostgreSQL DB and adding also a timestamp column to capture and save the exact point of data transmission. Now I want to transmit back to my webpage the contents, I've collected so far.

I searched [here](https://tecnotabs.com/spring-boot-project-with-jpa-mysql-and-jsp/) and although everything works fine, I am not able to display my data back to my webpage. I am providing a screenshot sample from my webpage, as well as my code so far. You can see also the HTML code at the end of this post.

1. Is it possible to play with Thymeleaf and JSP, on HTML at the same time?
2. Any help would be appreciated

[image: Results]

**Main Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class IotApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IotApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**EntityClass**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Table
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BitPayRates {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "bitpay_sequence",
            sequenceName = "bitpay_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
            )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "bitpay_sequence"
    )
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private Long rate;

    private java.time.LocalDateTime timestamp;

    protected BitPayRates() {
    }

    public BitPayRates(String code, String name, Long rate, LocalDateTime timestamp) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.rate = rate;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    // Getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BitPayRates{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", code='" + code + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", rate=" + rate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

//The controller for the project, which handles HTTP requests
@RestController
public class RestSpringBootController {

    //Dependency injection to connect with Service layer
    private final Service service;

    @Autowired
    public RestSpringBootController(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/bitpay")
    public List<List<BitPayRates>> getData(){
        return service.getData();
    }
}
```

**Controller 2 Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay.controller;

import com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay.service.Service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    Service service;

    @Autowired
    public WelcomeController(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Value("${welcome.message}")
    private String message;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", message);

        return "welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String mainWithParam(
            @RequestParam(name = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "")
            String name, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message", name);

        return "welcome";
    }

    @GetMapping("/show-contents")
    public String showAllRates(HttpServletRequest request){
        request.setAttribute("rates", service.showAllRates());
        request.setAttribute("mode","ALL_CONTENTS");
        return "databasecontents";
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay.service;

import com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay.model.BitPayRates;
import com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay.repository.BitPayRatesRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

//The service layer class for business logic implementation
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
@Transactional
public class Service {

    //Dependency injection to connect with Repository layer
    private final BitPayRatesRepo bitPayRatesRepo;

    @Autowired
    public Service(BitPayRatesRepo bitPayRatesRepo) {
        this.bitPayRatesRepo = bitPayRatesRepo;
    }

    public List<List<BitPayRates>> getData() {
        return Collections.singletonList(bitPayRatesRepo.findAll());
    }

    public List<BitPayRates> showAllRates(){
        List<BitPayRates> rates = new ArrayList<>();
        rates.addAll(bitPayRatesRepo.findAll());

        return rates;
    }
}
```

**Repository Interface**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

//Interface that multiple classes can use and connects with data JPA
//The JPA is a map that takes the variables mapped in BitPayRates class
//as first parameter and as second, returns the data type of the Id.
@Repository
public interface BitPayRatesRepo
        extends JpaRepository<BitPayRates,Integer> {

}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
package com.andrekreou.iot.bitpay;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

//The configuration class to fetch data from url and execute the insertion
//of the data into the PostgreSQL database
@Configuration
public class BitPayRatesConfig {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(BitPayRatesRepo bitPayRatesRepo) {
        return args -> {

            String url = "https://bitpay.com/api/rates";
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            ResponseEntity<List<BitPayRates>> postEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                });


        List<BitPayRates> results = postEntity.getBody();
        bitPayRatesRepo.saveAll(results);
        System.out.println(results);
        };
    }
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>Spring Boot Thymeleaf Hello World Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles/main.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:8080/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Andreas-Kreouzos">Github</a></li>
</ul>

<main role="main" class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>IoT Application</h1>
    </div>

</main>

<c:when test="${mode=='ALL_CONTENTS' }">
    <div class="container text-center" id="tasksDiv">
        <h3>Database Contents</h3>
        <hr>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Timestamp</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <c:forEach var="rate" items="${rates}">
                    <tr>
                        <td> <c:out value="${rate.id}"/> </td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${rate.code}"/> </td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${rate.name'"/> </td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${rate.rate}"/> </td>
                        <td> <c:out value="${rate.timestamp}"/> </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
</c:when>


</body>
</html>
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.andrekreou</groupId>
    <artifactId>iot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>iot</name>
    <description>MSc Thesis</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.45</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view) can help you.

Use `Model` to return rates. It's more easier than your approach. Something like this.

```
@GetMapping("/show-contents")
public String showAllRates(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("rates", service.showAllRates());
    model.addAttribute("mode", "ALL_CONTENTS");
    return "databasecontents";
}
```